# How to replace escape special characters while substring replacing in Oracle?

Tags: regex, oracle, replace, substring

There is a temp table with words and word_id. There are words in the temp table with special characters like . , - . The word_id's are updated from the main table escaping the special characters.

For example we have "digits." & "numbers-" in temp table.
The main_table has digits & numbers.

I need to replace the words in the temp table to www.xxx.com/"word"(without the special characters)/"word_id". Since the temp table has "digits." I am expecting it to be "www.xxx.com/digits/123". Need to retain the special characters as is be it at the beginning/end.

```
update temp set temp.word = '<a href=www.xxx.com/'||temp.word||'/'||temp.word_id where temp.word where temp.word_id is not null;
```

This code gives www.xxx.com/digits./123 but I am expecting it to be www.xxx.com/digits/123.

```
Here is the test data:

CREATE TABLE TEMP
   (ID NUMBER,
    WORD VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
    WORD_ID NUMBER
);

CREATE TABLE main_table
   (ID NUMBER,
    WORD VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE));

insert into temp(id,word) values (1, 'digits.');
insert into temp(id,word) values (2, '.numbers-');

insert into main_table values(111, 'digits');
insert into main_table values(222, 'numbers');
```

The temp table would look like

```
ID    WORD      WORD_ID
1     digits.    111
2     numbers-   222

The expected outcome is

ID    WORD      WORD_ID
1     www.xxx.com/digits/111.    111
2     www.xxx.com/numbers/222-   222
```

Comment: `www.xxx.com/numbers/222-` <-- can you explain why the `222` has a dash after it?

Comment: That's because we have numbers- . I just need to replace the numbers and retain the dash as is. Any special characters at the beginning/end for that matter.

Comment: I don't get it, and I can't seem to correlate the data in your expected output with the two source tables.

Comment: For ex: There is a sentence "Number 8 and 9 are digits."I am breaking down each of the words in to rows in temp table by space. So the last row is "digits." I need to replace it with www.xxx.com/digits/111 and should retain the special character at the end as I have to merge all the rows to form the sentence back but with the links. We have taken this approach as per the business needs. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Possibly try the REPLACE command

```
update temp set temp.word = '<a href=www.xxx.com/'||
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(temp.word,'.',''),'-',''),',','')
||'/'||temp.word_id where temp.word_id is not null;
```